# Is it possible to modify the mongo_client parameters that meteor uses?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

In short, with say Python, I can do:

```
client.write_concern = { 'w': 1, 'j': True, 'fsync': True }
```

in order to:

1. Set mongo client to provides acknowledgement of writes on a standalone box
2. Confirm that the `mongod` instance has written the data to the on-disk journal
3. Force the database to `fsync` all files before returning

But I don't see anyway to do this with Meteor. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

I think it already does this by default:

If you see the package `https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js`

Safe is enabled (which is to get acknowledgment of writes)

```
var options = {db: {safe: true}};
```

Comment: Thank you, but isn't safe:1 acknowledgement of writes to memory with eventual writes to journal on disk? As opposed to {w:1, j=True} which guarantees acknowledgements of disk writes to the journal?

Comment: Ah so safe is w:1 only? If you want you could add the j:true to make it write to the journal first